Scanning software to digitize family photos and slides
We have around 3,000-6,000 family photos and slides.
SCANNING SOFTWARE:  The best-sounding scan software I ran across is Vuescan.  Will it scan rapidly on an Epson FF-680W or FF-640 like the Epson software?  Any other software to consider?

You also need to specify the computer system that you will use.  I have an Epson scanner that works with an Intel based mac, but doesn't with an Apple Silicon  based mac.  I experimented with Vuescan and that seemed to solve the problem for a little bit, but then it failed again.  After exchanging emails with the Vuescan developer he stated that it relies on the underlying driver in the OS.

This is multiple questions in one, and thus too broad for the scope of Photo.SE. Please edit your question to focus on one issue, and ask multiple new questions if needed, for each major issue.

Perhaps the first step should be to edit the thousands of prints (negatives?) and slides to extract only the very best or relevant, leaving the other 5500 for another session.

Facing the same problem. Scanner not good enough (distorts more than a decent lens). Currently shooting everything with with a camera (slides and prints). DPI isn't a realistic criterion, you want a more or less constant pixels count for all pictures (ie, fill the frame). The 12Mpix of my old/spare camera are good enough (20"x14" prints at 200DPI).

You say you need to scan "photos and slides". What does "photos" mean? Negatives? Prints? Scan resolution needs to be quite different for prints and for slides.

Vuescan compatibility with Epson scanners is usually near perfect.  In this case it would be recommended because Vuescan has good automation settings to help with batch scanning.
Given the purpose of this scanner I would check if the professional mode in Epson Scan works well enough for your purposes too.  The workflow automation features of Epson Scan are usually not as good as Vuescan, but they do exist, and may take less time getting used-to than the advanced feature sets of Vuescan. As with most other things in Photography it's worth spending some time with the cheap tools to figure out your pain points.

Thanks!  I'll have at least two scanning workflows, one for each type of scanner:  a sheet-fed scanner for (hopefully) most prints; and a flatbed scanner for the remaining prints.  Makes it a bit more worthwhile to get to know Vuescan.  Slide scanning will be a later question to take up.
